# How to use global variables created from string inside the same function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I'm trying to extract data from a SPICE netlist file, specifically the defined parameters. This are the contents (of interest) of the file 'netlist.sp':

```
.param freq = 860x powS = 0
    + pi = 3.141592
    + nper = 15 cap1 = 68p 
    + cycles = 20 
    + tper = '1/freq'       
    + tstep = 'tper/nper'
    + tstop = 'cycles*tper'
```

FYI, the `+` sign means to continue the previous line, and the `param = 'equation'` evaluates the expression.

So, I'm trying to create a global variable inside Python 3.6 for each one of the parameters. This is the code I got so far:

```
def isnumber(s):
try:
    float(s)
    return True
except ValueError:
    return False

#This function is needed to convert the '68p' format to '68e-12'
def floatify(st):
    if not isnumber(st[-1]):
        vals = [ 't', 'g', 'x', 'meg', 'k', 'm',  'u',  'n',  'p',   'f',   'a']
        prod = [1e12, 1e9, 1e6,  1e6,  1e3, 1e-3, 1e-6, 1e-9, 1e-12, 1e-15, 1e-18]
        pos  = vals.index(st[-1])
        st = st[:-1]
        num = float(st) * prod[pos]
    else:
            num  = float(st)
    return num

#This is the main function
def params (file):
    fl = 0
    strng = '00'
    tnum  = 0.0
    with open(file) as dat:
        for line in dat:
            if line.startswith('*'):
                pass
            elif line.startswith('.param '):
                fl = 1
                spl = line.split()
                a = [i for i,x in enumerate(spl) if x=='=']
                for i in range(len(a)):
                    strng = spl[a[i]-1]
                    try:
                        tnum = floatify(spl[a[i]+1])
                    except ValueError:
                        tnum = eval(spl[a[i]+1])
                    globals()[strng] = tnum
            elif (line.find('+')+1) and fl:
                spl = line.split()
                a = [i for i,x in enumerate(spl) if x=='=']
                for i in range(len(a)):
                    strng = spl[a[i]-1]
                    try:
                        tnum = floatify(spl[a[i]+1])
                    except ValueError:
                        temp = spl[a[i]+1]
                        tnum = eval(temp)
                    globals()[strng] = tnum
            elif (not (line.find('+')+1)) and fl:
                break

params('netlist.sp')

#Testing the variables
print('params done')
print('freq = ', freq)
print('powS = ', powS)
print('pi = ', pi)
print('nper = ', nper)
print('cap1 = ', cap1)
print('cycles = ', cycles)
print('tper = ', tper)
print('tstep = ', tstep)
print('tstop = ', tstop)

# Testing the eval function:
print(eval('1/freq'))
print(eval('2*pi'))
```

The `globals()[strng] = tnum` statement creates the global variable from the extracted string and assigns the corresponding value.

The output is:

```
freq =  860000000.0
powS =  0.0
pi =  3.141592
nper =  15.0
cap1 =  6.8e-11
cycles =  20.0
tper =  1/freq
tstep =  tper/nper
tstop =  cycles*tper
1.1627906976744186e-09
6.283184
```

So, what I understand from the testing of the `eval` function is that the global variables created inside the `params` function are understood only outside of the function itself. I know that to modify a global variable inside a function you have to declare the `global var` statement inside the function. My question is how to do that in this case when the variables are created dynamically?

Comment: Why not just make a `params = {}` dict and then fill it with whatever you desire and use `global params` to access it in functions.

Comment: Yes, I thought about using a dictionary, but that would make much more complicated to use the `eval` function to extract the values of parameters defined by expressions.

Comment: You don't have to eval them, that's the point. And from looking over your code you are over-complicating the whole thing.

Comment: It seems over-complicated because this is a very simple case, the parameters can be defined even with mathematical functions `param3 = sin(param1)+exp(param2)`. So I think the `eval` function is the best bet, unless you know a simpler way with dictionaries. Remeber that I got a string expression in the first place and the alternative would involve parsing the string expression to a python equation format which is exactly what the eval function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The repl.it could be cleaned up quite a bit, but it does work for the example data.

As this [repl.it](https://repl.it/J5ss/3) shows, you can do this painlessly with a dictionary.

```
def fill_param(token):
    for key in params.keys():
        token = token.replace(key, str(params[key]))
    return token
```

is the key which allows this: it uses str.replace to fill in the values for anything we already know before we `eval` it:

```
params[key] = eval(fill_param(value))
```

The start of `process_params()` is interesting as well:

```
global params
tokens = shlex.split(line)[1:]
```

we import the dictionary, then use `shlex.split()` to tokenize the string, leaving off the first token (`.param` or `+` depending on the line). `shlex.split()` is nice because it respects quotations.

---

Full code (in case repl.it dies). Note it leaves a lot to be desired, as I'm spent on this problem. I leave the clean-up as an exercise to the reader.

```
import shlex

with open("netlist.sp", "w") as f:
    f.write("""cabbage
garbage
.param freq = 860x powS = 0
+ pi = 3.141592
+ nper = 15 cap1 = 68p 
+ cycles = 20 
+ tper = '1/freq'       
+ tstep = 'tper/nper'
+ tstop = 'cycles*tper'
sweet american freedom""")

params = {}
def param_it(in_f):

    def isnumber(s):
        try:
            float(s)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def floatify(st):
        if not isnumber(st):
            vals = [ 't', 'g', 'x', 'meg', 'k', 'm',  'u',  'n',  'p',   'f',   'a']
            prod = [1e12, 1e9, 1e6,  1e6,  1e3, 1e-3, 1e-6, 1e-9, 1e-12, 1e-15, 1e-18]
            pos  = vals.index(st[-1])
            st = st[:-1]
            num = float(st) * prod[pos]
        else:
                num  = float(st)
        return num

    def number(st):
        if isnumber(st) or len(st) == 1 and st in '0123456789':
            return True
        return st[-1] not in '0123456789' and isnumber(st[:-1])

    def process_params(line):
        global params
        tokens = shlex.split(line)[1:]
        assert len(tokens) % 3 == 0
        for i in range(len(tokens)/3):
            key = tokens[i*3]
            value = tokens[i*3 + 2]
            print "Processing key: %s value: %s... " % (key, value),

            if number(value):
                try:
                    value = float(value)
                except ValueError:
                    value = floatify(value)
                params[key] = value
            else:
                try:
                    params[key] = eval(fill_param(value))
                except Exception as e:  # eval can throw essentially any exception
                    print "Failed to parse value for k/v %s:%s" % (key, value)
                    raise
            print "Converted value is : %s\n" % params[key]

    def fill_param(token):
        for key in params.keys():
            token = token.replace(key, str(params[key]))
        return token

    with open(in_f, "r") as f:
        param = False
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(".param "):
                process_params(line)
                param = True
            elif param and line.startswith("+"):
                process_params(line)
            elif param:
                break

param_it("netlist.sp")

print params
```

Comment: Yes, this does what I wanted. I'm sorry if I sounded stubborn, I didn't knew about the `shlex` package. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @SalatielGarcia `shlex` is meant for command line processing, but in this case I think it will work for you.